# Excel formula for sum of income over multiple years adjusted for inflation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, mathematica

I have the income `X`, and the number of years in the future `Y`, and the inflation `Z`. I can calculate the compound interest simply by `CI(Y) = X*(1+Z)^Y` for any given year, but how can I construct a formula that adds each years income together for a total sum?

Ex)

```
X = 1000
Y = 3
Z = 5%
CI(0) = $1000
CI(1) = $1050
CI(2) = $1102,5
CompoundInterestSum(3) = $3152,5
```

I could do this in code recursively, but I'd like to know the cleaner formula that I can use in Excel. Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of formulas -> financial in excel that can accomplish what you desire. However, it looks like CI(1) should be 1050, etc. In otherwords, C(0) should be 1000. Also, your calculation is the principal and interest. therefore your CompoundInterestSum(3) is overstated. If you think not, then I would like to invest in your company...

Comment: Thanks! You are correct and I've updated to start at a zero-based index. What do you mean by overstated in the example? My actual scenario is calculating total returns on solar power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=-FV(z,y,x) or =FV(z,y,-x)

This calculates the Future Value of a stream of amounts based on the interest rate per period, the number of periods, and the amount added each period.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FV-function-2EEF9F44-A084-4C61-BDD8-4FE4BB1B71B3

Comment: I was looking at this function earlier, but it returns a negative value and it's described as used for loans. Looking into it further it seems the result is the same as long as the value is negated, so if you updated your answer with a - or *-1 for clarity I will mark it as correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jsmars, that's strange that it comes out negative. Apparently it has to do with tradition with how finance people think of (+) and (-)... good catch, I'll update